# How can I plot a sector of an ellipse using the central angle and not the Eccentric Anomaly?

Tags: graphics, geometry, filling

It would appear that the [`Disk`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Disk.html) function, when asked to produce the sector of an ellipse between two angles treats those angles as Eccentric Anomalies (i.e. arguments to a parametric plot) rather than true central angles (i.e. arguments to a polar plot). The first part of my question asks whether this observation is correct?

Given that I want to construct a sector using the true central angles, I know that I can make use of the polar equation `(r=(a*b)/Sqrt[(b Cos[θ])^2+(a Sin[θ])^2];)`, but this does not provide me `Disk`'s ability to color the resultant sector. So, the second part of my question is, does *Mathematica* provide me a function for performing this filling operation?

I am aware of the [`Filling`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Filling.html) option to [`Plot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Plot.html). If it is, in fact, the preferred approach, can anyone provide an example of its use for doing elliptical sectors?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think these functions do what you want. First the length from the centre of the ellipse to a point on its perimeter.

```
EllipsePolarRadius[t_, a_, b_] := a*b/Sqrt[(a Sin[t])^2 + (b Cos[t])^2]
```

Next a conversion from eccentric anomaly to central angle that works when input to `Disk`.

```
AngleConversionForDisk[t_, a_, b_] :=
   Which[
      0 <= t < Pi/2, ArcTan[a*Tan[t]/b],
      t == Pi/2, Pi/2,
      Pi/2 < t < 3 Pi/2, ArcTan[a*Tan[t]/b] + Pi,
      t == 3 Pi/2, 3 Pi/2,
      3 Pi/2 < t <= 2 Pi, ArcTan[a*Tan[t]/b] + 2 Pi]
```

And a `Manipulate` to illustrate the relationships.

```
Manipulate[
   Module[{a = 2, b = 4, u},
      u = AngleConversionForDisk[t, a, b];
      Graphics[{Thick,
         Circle[{0, b}, {a, b}],(* ellipse *)
         Cyan, Disk[{0, b}, {a, b}, {0, u}], (* ellipse sector *)
          (* t parameterization *)
         Black, Line[{{0, b}, {a Cos[t], b Sin[t]} + {0, b}}],
         (* u parameterization *)
         Red, Line[{{0, b}, EllipsePolarRadius[t, a, b]*{Cos[t], Sin[t]} + {0, b}}]
         }, Frame -> True, GridLines -> {Range[-a, a], Range[0, 2 b]},
         PlotLabel -> "Central Angle: " <> ToString[N[t]/Degree] <> " degrees"]],
   {{t, 0.2, "Central Angle"}, 0., 2.*Pi, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

[image: ellipse sector]

Comment: `AngleConversionForDisk[]` looks like it can be expressed better with two-argument arctangent. See [this article](http://dx.doi.org/10.1080/2151237X.2011.563679) by Glassner as well.

Comment: This is exactly what I need.

BTW, I am familiar with using the expansion factor a/b to transform a y coordinate from an ellipse to the circumscribed circle. But I am unfamiliar with its use in the context of ArcTan[a*Tan[t]/b]. Can you explain a bit how this works, or give me a pointer to a resource?

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks! The connection between the central angle and the eccentric anomaly is discussed, for example, [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipse#Parametric_form_in_canonical_position).